# Can we see , what password or PIN is being typed in on windows login screen on event viewer

Tags: windows, logging, passwords, audit, event-viewer

Can we see , what password or PIN is being typed in on windows login screen in event viewer , because as of now i have only been able to see Audit success or audit failure logs in Event viewer [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBpKw.png)

I tried setting the group policy to enable the auditing but it didn't made any diffrence .

Comment: Pretty sure no security product would allow logging password/pin values

Comment: Can we add tampering to policy to somehow log the passwords or PINs which are attempted ? even in hashed format

Comment: Simple answer is no. Why don't you ask the user for the password? What are you trying to achieve? By the way... Read the tour of stackoverflow and you will see your question should be ask somewhere else.